# closed,bounded not compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Hi I was asked to prove that: if $S =\{ x \in \Bbb R : d(x,0) = 1 \}$ then $S$ is a closed and bounded set.

The set $S$ contains only two points: $-1,1$,(it should not be a problem to prove that is it closed and bounded)but it gets really confusing when iam also asked to show that $S$ is not compact if $S$ is  A  or $B$, where $A$ is the set of all real sequences $\{c_n \}$ such that $\{c_n \}$  is bounded , $B$ is the set of all real sequences $\{k_n\}$  such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }k_n = 0$.

Comment: I inferred from the tag that the space you were working with was the reals. If this is not correct, please correct your definition of $S$ to the form $$S=\{x\in X:d(x,0)=1\},$$ where $X$ is the space you're working in. It makes no sense to put $$S=\{x\in S:d(x,0)=1\},$$ as you originally had.

Answer (score 1):

> the set $S$ contains only two points $-1$ and $1$.

Careful: it would be true if $S$ is the real line endowed with the usual metric, but here it is supposed to be a general metric (normed, as $0$ belongs in) space.

Closeness follows from continuity of the map $y\mapsto d(x,y)$, where $x$ is fixed. It's a consequence of triangular inequality.

Indeed, it's not necessarily compact. If $S$ is the space of convergent or bounded sequences endowed with the supremum norm, then $S$ contains $T=\{e^{(k)},k\geqslant 1\}$ where $e^{(k)}_j=1$ if $j=k$ and $0$ otherwise. Since $d(e^{(k_1)},e^{(k_2)})=1$ if $k_1\neq k_2$, $T$ cannot be compact.

Comment: i dont get the $e^{(k)}$ notation

Comment: $e^{(k)}$ is a sequence whose terms are specified.

Comment: For example, when $k_1=1$ and $k_2=2$, we have $d(x^{(1)},x^{(2)})=\lVert (1,-1,0,\dots,0,\dots\rVert_\infty$.

Comment: i dont get this part now: $d(e^{(k_1)},e^{(k_2)})=1$ if $k_1\neq k_2$ ,why cannot T be compact

Comment: It depends on the definition of compactness you have at your disposal. If it's "for each sequence we can extract a convergent subsequence", you can see it's not the case (as the Cauchy condition does not work for $\varepsilon=1/3$). If it's with open covers, consider $B(x^{(j)},1/2)$.